# Why does ls -lSh command return very small file sizes?

Tags: bash, ls, iterm2

When using the ls -lSh command, the output of the size of the files is very small. For instance:

ls -lSh | grep Xcode.app #my command to terminal while in Applications directory

drwxr-xr-x@  3 root   wheel    96B Dec 17 14:59 Xcode.app #output

As you can see, Xcode is only 96B, when in reality is over 6GB on disk. Can somebody please explain the formula being applied here?

I am running iTerm2 on macosx catalina

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could better fit in https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That is a directory and the size is perfectly right for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` does not report *size of whole directory*, but only *the directory entry itself*. If you want aggregate directory size, you should use `du` or similar utilities that count sizes recursively. The size output from `ls` is the size of the directory entry, which generally grows if you have more files and subdirectories, but not when you have large single files, and depends a lot on the underlying filesystem.

Comment: Can you explain (or point me to a link) in detail the discrepancy in size between using du -sh (outputs 9.0GB), and cmd + i in finder (9.62GB on disk)?

Comment: @nomadj I am unsure about macOS, but `du` command reports **d**isk **u**sage, while File Info reports "apparent size", i.e. the size a file claims to have. Try creating a big empty file with `truncate -s 1G filename` and compare both tools on the file.

Comment: in this case ls -lh returns the alloted size of the empty file (1GB), du -sh returns used space(0B), and info returns both, with the allotted size being more precise(1.07GB). In both cases there is a 7% difference.

Comment: @nomadj macOS File Info uses 1000-based units, while CLI utilities often use 1024-based units, so 1 GB in `ls` or `du` equals to 1,073,741,824 bytes, corresponding to the 1.073 GB shown by Finder.

Answer (score 2):

.app are actually directories, nor regular files. Try `du -sh Xcode.app` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `-l` switch shows the "allocated size" of the item you're listing. In case of a directory, its size amounts to just its entry in the file system, and that is very small. What one normally thinks of as the "size" of a directory is actually taken by the files residing beneath it, and that is reported by the `du` command.

Comment: Note that a file can be in multiple directories, so considering the file to be part of the directory's size makes no sense.